# Apple Aperture profile name (sRGB IEC61966-2.1 vs Camera RGB Profile)

Tags: apple-aperture, color-spaces

I have a bunch of duplicate photos in Aperture. They came from separate iPhoto libraries. Some of the photos have the profile name `sRGB IEC61966-2.1` and others `Camera RGB Profile`.  Which should I keep?  Does it make a difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, `sRGB IEC61966-2.1` is the standard sRGB color profile and the one that you want to be using. My understanding is that `Camera RGB Profile` happens on iPhoto import when the color profile isn't present in the image during the import. Other than the gamma (sRGB is 2.2, this is 1.8), the profiles are identical, but that a lot of devices and computers won't recognize the `Camera RGB Profile` because it isn't a standard one. Ideally, if you can, try to convert to the sRGB profile in Aperture.

Have a look at Apple's KB article on [Aperture: Color and gamma settings for print and web](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2026) for some ideas on correcting. I'm not an Aperture user, so I can't really help there.

Answer (score 0):

I used to have my camera and editing programs (mostly Photoshop) set to sRGB, but after reading numerous articles I decided to set my colour settings to Adobe RGB (1998). It gives you the most accurate/rich colours from your shoot. This article puts it in perspective: http://fstoppers.com/adobergb-vs-srgb